# Do I need a server for ajax calls in a sencha touch app?

Tags: ajax, extjs, sencha-touch

I want to package a Sencha Touch app to deploy to multiple mobile platforms (iOS/Android). I know that cross-domain AJAX requests are not possible for browsers, but is it possible to make cross-domain AJAX calls in a Sencha Touch app? (no server, and packaged to iOS/Android using something like PhoneGap)

I want to hit a third-party API within the Sencha Touch app using AJAX but I'm under the impression that I need a server to wrap the third-party API to avoid the cross-domain issue. Someone please clarify.

Answer (score 1):

Cross-domain AJAX request are possible with [`JSONP`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) using a [`Ext.data.proxy.JsonP`](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP).
I don't know what your API looks like but use it something like this:

```
var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
    autoLoad: true,
    //model: , //Your API
    proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url : 'http://domain.com/request',
        callbackKey: 'theCallbackFunction'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSONP, but you can also use normal JSON.

The phones browser will allow cross domain requests when the files are "local" ie wrapped in phonegap.

Answer (score 0):

As A1rPun says Cross-domain AJAX requests are possible with JSONP(JSON with Padding) using [Ext.data.proxy.JsonP](http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.JsonP)

**Sencha touch-2 Approach:**

```
Ext.define('YourStore', {
       extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

       config: {
           fields: ['field1', 'field2', 'field3'],

           proxy: {
               type: 'jsonp',
               url:'YourUrl',
               callbackKey: 'jsoncallback',
               extraParams : {
                    method : 'YourUrl.method',
                    api_key : 'PUTYOURKEYHERE',
                    format : 'json',
                    nojsoncallback : 1
               },
               reader: {
                   type: 'json'
               }
           }
       }
   });
```